# PXE boot from physical computer and virtual machine doesn't happen equally

Tags: pxe

I've set up a WDS server and connected it to my local network switch. When I PXE-boot any physically connected computer with PXE 2.0 on that network, everything works just fine. It boots into Windows PE.

But when I boot up an Oracle Virtual Machine on my development computer that is also on the same network switch, with PXE 2.1, which is configured as "bridged" on that same network, I get the following error message:
PXE-E55: ProxyDHCP service did not reply to request on port 4011.

So my guestion is, why does my virtual machine responds differently than a physically connected computer? Both get IP-address from the same DHCP server in the same range 192.168.1.xxx

For easy troubleshooting, I disabled the firewall on the WDS server on every network profile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would not expect the two systems to be the same.

The host system BIOS (UEFI) get a Network Connection using Ethernet for the PXE Boot.

The Virtual Machine gets its network from the Host machine either for NAT or for passthrough to the router for Bridged but that will not be known until the machine starts and knows Bridged or Network Connection.

So when you try PXE Boot on the Virtual Machine, the VM network as not started and so you get the "DHCP did not reply" message.

You can try different adapters in VBOX to see if that helps.

I do not know for sure but what you are trying to do may work in a VMware ESX environment where ESX machines have more hardware resources available to them.

Comment: Looks like I managed to get it to work. I did the following: I disabled the VirtualBox Host-Only Network adapter and then restarted the WDS service.

Comment: I mad a small change in my answer to see if you can find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
PXE-E55: ProxyDHCP service did not reply to request on port 4011.
```

This error tells you that the virtual machine is getting an IP by DHCP but that offer did not contain PXE booting information (TFTP server IP and name of the NBP) and that there's was not a proxyDHCP server providing that info either.

This could be i.e. because your VM got the IP from the Virtual Environment DHCP server which does not know where your PXE server is located and you did not have a properly configured proxyDHCP Server in place.

You solved the problem when the VM got its IP from the DHCP server that contains the booting information, surely the one used by your WDS server.